# Is it reasonable to argue that my party should start with inspiration, since I have the Musician feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, inspiration

I chose the 1st-level feat *Musician* for my bard that I'm going to play in the campaign I'm starting. This feat is from the One D&D playtest, and reads like this:

> **Musician**
>
> - **Instrument Training**. You gain Tool Proficiency with three Musical Instruments of your choice.
> - **Inspiring Song**. As you finish a Short Rest or a Long Rest, you can play a song on a Musical Instrument with which you have Tool Proficiency and give Heroic Inspiration to allies who hear the song. The number of allies you can affect in this way equals your Proficiency Bonus.

Is it reasonable to say that the rest of the party should start with Inspiration each session?

Note that Heroic Inspiration is just a fancy term for Inspiration.

I'm playing a third-level character, so I can affect two people per rest with this ability. There are 3-4 other people in my party.

I made my character using the creation guide provided for me by my DM, so I know my character is fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Not necessarily

It is clear when you cause others to gain Inspiration, and you can not skip that trigger:

> **As you finish a Short Rest or a Long Rest**, you can [cause Inspiration]

Unless the GM specifies that you **had** a chance to start the session at a Short Rest or Long Rest, then you can not cause Inspiration with this feat at the start of a session.

Denying this would be typical for *picking up right where you left off* - at which point you'd need to declare at least such a rest to cause Inspiration. It would be absolutely **not** be reasonable to use the "new session" argument to restock inspirations right when you... opened the door to the dungeon heart, or in round 3 of a battle.

If your characters left the last session by returning to town, and the new session starts with "The next morning...", then the argument to ask if you had the chance for a long rest and could benefit from your feat makes sense - but still, the GM might have reasons to deny this, because you might have had a party for the ages and most decidedly not rested to the degree required by a Rest.

Comment: I assume we'd have at least a day of downtime between sessions.

Comment: @User23415 Right, that is precisely the assumption that Trish is saying may not be reasonable. That may not always be true.

Comment: There are some GMs who quite like ending the session at a dramatic point (eg., just after you've opened the door and seen the dragon lying on its hoard), and I can't count the number of times a combat encounter has run longer than expected and we've had to pause in the middle (one of the major advantages of VTTs that save all that state).

Comment: @User23415 that's an assumption you need to clarify with your DM and it's not really common in my experience. From my experience most/all DMs tell you when they want to give you downtime.

Comment: @User23415 As a very concrete example for how your first session might start, the DM might decide that the party are brought together by happenstance - you're all strangers who happened to visit the same tavern on one fateful night when the zombies attacked or whatever. In that scenario, it clearly doesn't make sense that your bard was able to play music for the rest of the party the night before - you've only just met! As we're all saying - check with your GM for the specific narrative circumstances

Answer (score 6):

#### Only if your characters know each other and have traveled together as the campaign starts

As per the feature description, you can only use it during a long or short rest.
Thus, if your party has been traveling and resting together before the start of the campaign, then yes, you could reasonably assume that you would have used this feature during the last rest.

Bear in mind, of course, that this is still subject to your DM's approval.

Conversely, if your party is meeting in a tavern for the first time as the campaign starts, then they would not have rested together before, and as such, the other members definitely would NOT have the bonus.

(Naturally, if you travelled with only some, but not all, party members before, only those would receive the bonus)

This answer doesn't apply to session start either, only to campaign start. There is no "automatic downtime" between session, this depends entirely on the DM, and where you ended the last session.